# (TensorFlowLite Model Maker) ValueError: Expect x to be a non-empty array or dataset (Colab)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, google-mlkit

I have this problem too: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63231811/valueerror-expect-x-to-be-a-non-empty-array-or-dataset-tensor-flow-lite-model)

I added the len(train_data) & len(test_data) line :

```
data = ImageClassifierDataLoader.from_folder(image_path)
train_data, test_data = data.split(0.9)
len(train_data)
```

> And I got this error: "TypeError: object of type 'ImageClassifierDataLoader' has no len()"

Can anyone solve the problem? :(

.

Comment: Try `train_data.size`

Comment: Are you using your own training data? I replied in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63231811/valueerror-expect-x-to-be-a-non-empty-array-or-dataset-tensor-flow-lite-model Could you try that?

Answer (score 1):

This Error is caused by the size of training data is smaller than `batch_size` which is not allowed. The default batch_size is 32, which means the number of training images should be no less than 32.

You need to choose one of the following solutions to solve it.

- Set `batch_size` smaller than training data size, e.g:

```
image_classifier.create(train_data, batch_size=4)
```

- Increase the size of training data by adding more data.

As for `len()`, we have added it. You could try `len(train_data)` again or use `train_data.size`.