# Tensorflow - ValueError: Expect x to be a non-empty array or dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying the IMU classification code in the example below. I have added magnetometer data differently. I changed the code in a few places and got this error code.

https://colab.research.google.com/github/arduino/ArduinoTensorFlowLiteTutorials/blob/master/GestureToEmoji/arduino_tinyml_workshop.ipynb

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(15, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(NUM_GESTURES, activation='softmax')) 
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
history = model.fit(inputs_train, outputs_train, epochs=100, batch_size=1, validation_data=(inputs_validate, outputs_validate))
```

error:

```
Epoch 1/100
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-020cb61ad29f> in <module>()
      5 model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(NUM_GESTURES, activation='softmax')) # softmax is used, because we only expect one gesture to occur per input
      6 model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
----> 7 history = model.fit(inputs_train, outputs_train, epochs=100, batch_size=1, validation_data=(inputs_validate, outputs_validate))
      8 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1108 
   1109         if logs is None:
-> 1110           raise ValueError('Expect x to be a non-empty array or dataset.')
   1111         epoch_logs = copy.copy(logs)
   1112 

ValueError: Expect x to be a non-empty array or dataset.
```

I tried to implement the solutions on Stackoverflow and Github. But I couldn't get any results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: Expect x to be a non-empty array or dataset (Tensor Flow lite model maker on Collab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63231811/valueerror-expect-x-to-be-a-non-empty-array-or-dataset-tensor-flow-lite-model)

Comment: Unfortunately no.